# determine the max interval on which the solution is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help in this problem

consider the following IVP :

$$y' = y^2 + e^{-x^2}, \; y(0) = 0$$

now I've tried to solve this equation by first solving the associated homogeneous equation which gives : $$y(x) ={-1\over x+K}$$

then by the method of variation of parameters I ended up with this equation : $$ {K'(x)\over (x+K^2(x))} =e^{-x^2}$$

which I don't think I could get anywhere from it

Comment: it is a Riccati type DE which is nonlinear

Comment: @daulomb Indeed. I did not notice. however, it's still not that easy to find a paricular solution to perform the Riccati change of variable. maybe you have a hint to give me ?

Comment: you need to know  a particular solution to write down the general solution. This is not easy, in general. By the way, in your title it is not asked to find the solution. just asked for determining max interval of existence

Comment: i got this here $$y(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{2 x+1}
   \text{erf}(x+1)-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }
   \text{erf}(1) e^{2 x+1}$$

Comment: i think the solution exists for all real $x$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thanks for the answer. just out of curiosity. did you get that by performing computations or using a mathematical symbolic computation program ?

Comment: We could arrive that conclusion directly without attempting to solve since $y'\geq e^{-x^2}\Longrightarrow y(x)\geq\int_0^x e^{-s^2}ds$

Comment: @daulomb NICE OBSERVATION !

Comment: @rapidracim: thanks but I am still not sure that the solution exists for all $x$ because if we compare with the other side, that is, if we let $y'\leq y^2+1$, then $y(x)\leq \tan x$, which is defined in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$